# One variable clobbers another

Tags: java, variables

I have a very weird situation. I have a class that has a couple of members, like this:

```
public class myMainClass
{
    public aClass myObject = new aClass();
    private int numberOfUpdates = 0;
    public anotheClass.memberClass anotherObject = new anotheClass.memberClass();
```

Note that the `anotherClass` has a class defined within it. (Not sure if that enters into the problem I'm having).

Both `aClass` and `anotheClass.memberClass` have a member with the same name, `ThisMember`.

I also have a method within `myMainClass` that does some modifications to the members of the `myMainClass` object:

```
public void Update(double aPassedInNumber)
{
    anotherObject.ThisMember  = aPassedInNumber;
    //etc
}
```

I'm *only* modifying that one member. However, when I do that, `myObject.ThisMember` *also* gets modified to the same value! It's as though (??) both member variables occupy the same location in memory. Or that one is somehow a reference to the other.

It's as if I had done:

```
public void Update(double aPassedInNumber)
{
    anotherObject.ThisMember = aPassedInNumber;
    myObject  =  aPassedInNumber;
    //etc
}
```

BUT I'M NOT. I'm only doing the first assignment, yet *both* of those variables get modified.

I've traced this and printed out diagnostics and used a watch window and it clearly modifies both variables.

How can that be? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you post a complete working example, and tell us what language this is?

Comment: Is one of those members static?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, man. It looks like I still don't have a handle on the reference concept in JAVA. That one variable is indeed simply a reference to the other object.

Now it seems I have to implement a copy method for the class.

Aaaargh!!

Comment: Do you solved your problem? Please post your solution and accept the answer as solution!